# Ruby don't do actions for nil class in if block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

How to achieve sth like if `params[:filters][:company_name]` is present (not nil) then do below actions but if it's nil - skip and do the rest of the code below/outside of this if ?

```
if params[:filters][:company_name]
  contains = Process
             .where(
               'company_name LIKE ?', "#{params[:filters][:company_name].downcase}%"
             )
end
```

Comment: Well, you can do it exactly as shown in your code. Do you experience any problem with it?

Comment: @HolgerJust This code will throw an error if `params[:filters]` is `nil`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm *assuming* your problem is that the code "blows up" if `params[:filters]` is `nil`. (You get an error: "undefined method `:[]` for `nil:NilClass`".)

There are multiple ways to handle this, but probably the most concise is to use [`Hash#dig`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig):

```
if params.dig(:filters, :company_name)
  # ...
end
```

This won't fail if `params[:filters] == nil`. From the above linked documentation (emphasis is mine):

> Extracts the nested value specified by the sequence of key objects by calling dig at each step, **returning nil if any intermediate step is nil**.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if params[:filters][:company_name]
```

to

```
if params[:filters] && params[:filters][:company_name]
```